# Is net.namedPipe binding required for AppFabric

Tags: asp.net, appfabric

I am hosting ASP.NET website on Windows AppFabric. I am trying to use AutoStart feature of AppFabric to keep the site running.

I read on some blogs and on some microsoft forums, that net.namedPipe binding should be set for AppFabric to control the service. Is it really needed for AutoStart funcitonality?

References:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/09/08/death-to-windows-services-long-live-appfabric.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dublin/thread/be6bbfd0-5187-4004-ae04-080dd9331d82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

NamedPipeBinding is only used by the Management Service which enhances AppFabric management capabilities by providing clients the ability to start services remotely. It's used by workflow services (WCF services using Workflow Foundation).

In my company, I have enabled AutoStart without this binding and protocol.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383422.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it is running fine without NamedPipeBinding.